# In laravel, why I can't get the current user information?

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel I am trying to get the current user after logged in but I can't. Why I can't get the current user which is already logged in?

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        Auth::login($user);
        return ['message' => "Successfully Logged In"];
    }
    return ['error' => "Invalid Credentials"];
}

public function currentUser()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user) {
        return ["user" => $user];
    }
    return ["error" => "User Not Found"];
}

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

Route::post('/login',[UserController::class, 'login']);
Route::get('/getuser',[UserController::class, 'currentUser']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // If the login is successful, it's advisable to refresh the user's session to safeguard against session fixation.
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            // Authentication was successful, no need to call Auth::login($user)
            return ['message' => "Successfully Logged In"];
        }
        return ['error' => "Invalid Credentials"];
    }
```

You get the current logged in user by calling `auth()->user();`. To get logged in user email in blade use `{{ auth()->user()->email }}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call **Auth::login($user)** after using **Auth::attempt** because the **attempt** method already logs in the user if the credentials are correct. Make sure the guards are working correctly. If they are not, follow the solution mentioned above to regenerate the session."

```
 $request->session()->regenerate();
```